# XSLT transformation and string replacement

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to do something I am not entirely sure it is possible to do. If it is, then it is certainly beyond my reach and am hoping someone may be able to help me.

Here is a sample of an xml file I have...

```
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="255" hierarchykey="39">
    <td colname="1">&lt;A1&gt;Common stocks [Stop Here]87.33%</td>
    <td colname="2"/>
    <td colname="3"/>
    <td colname="4"/>
    <td colname="5"/>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="3" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="238" hierarchykey="40">
    <td colname="1">&lt;2&gt;Health care&amp;lt;softreturn&amp;gt;21.27%</td>
    <td colname="2"/>
    <td colname="3"/>
    <td colname="4"/>
    <td colname="5"/>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="4" itemtype="detail" securitymasterkey="1415" securitiescondensed="">
    <td colname="1"/>
    <td colname="2">Gillan Sciences, Inc. [Category Caption]</td>
    <td colname="3">26,522,142</td>
    <td colname="4">1,132,761</td>
    <td colname="5">4.12</td>
  </tr>
```

Now, what I would like to do is find the 'tr' node having an attribute of 'type = "detail"' with a 'td' element that contains the text '[Category Caption]', search backwards to the first predecessing 'tr' node having an attribute of 'type = "categoryhead"' and get the text from it's 'td' element between 'A1>' and '[Stop Here]' - and use that text to replace '[Category Caption]' in the 'detail' node. I then would like to strip out '[Stop Here]' from the 'categoryhead' node.

What I would like to end up with would look like this....

```
<tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="255" hierarchykey="39">
        <td colname="1">&lt;A1&gt;Common stocks 87.33%</td>
        <td colname="2" />
        <td colname="3" />
        <td colname="4" />
        <td colname="5" />
      </tr>
      <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="3" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="238" hierarchykey="40">
        <td colname="1">&lt;2&gt;Health care&amp;lt;softreturn&amp;gt;21.27%</td>
        <td colname="2" />
        <td colname="3" />
        <td colname="4" />
        <td colname="5" />
      </tr>
      <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="4" itemtype="detail" securitymasterkey="1415" securitiescondensed="">
        <td colname="1" />
        <td colname="2">Gillan Sciences, Inc. Common stocks</td>
        <td colname="3">26,522,142</td>
        <td colname="4">1,132,761</td>
        <td colname="5">4.12</td>
      </tr>
```

This is the xslt I have so far...

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v4:tr[@type = 'detail']/v4:td[contains(./text(), '[Category Caption]')]">
        <xsl:variable name="TargetReplacementToken" select="'[Category Caption]'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="CategoryRecordIdentificationTag" select="'A1>'"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $TargetReplacementToken)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after((preceding::v4:tr[@type = 'categoryhead']/v4:td[contains(., $CategoryRecordIdentificationTag)])[last()], $CategoryRecordIdentificationTag)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

...with 'v4' being the namespace I am using, but obviously it doesn't remove '[Stop Here]' from the text in the 'categoryhead' node, and also copies the entire text, i.e. 'Common stocks [Stop Here]87.33%' instead of just the substring 'Common Stocks'. I know this sounds rather confusing, I've tried to include as much detail as possible without turning this question into a novel so if anyone can help I would very much appreciate it but if you need any clarification on what I am trying to do then feel free to ask.

many thanks,
fordprefect141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the following stylesheet. Basically, you need an identity template, and the two templates to target your desired nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td[contains(., '[Category Caption]')][parent::tr[@type='detail']]">

        <!-- the target td with text -->
        <xsl:variable name="TargetText">
            <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::tr[@type='categoryhead']/td[contains(., '[Stop Here]')]"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- the filtered text -->
        <xsl:variable name="ReplacementText" select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after($TargetText, 'A1&gt;'), '[Stop Here]'))">
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., '[Category Caption]'), $ReplacementText)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- strip the text from the target node -->
    <xsl:template match="td[contains(., '[Stop Here]')][parent::tr[@type='categoryhead']]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '[Stop Here]')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '[Stop Here]')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs (I have added a `root` tag from your sample input XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="255" hierarchykey="39">
      <td colname="1">&lt;A1&gt;Common stocks 87.33%</td>
      <td colname="2"/>
      <td colname="3"/>
      <td colname="4"/>
      <td colname="5"/>
   </tr>
   <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="3" itemtype="categoryhead" categorykey="238" hierarchykey="40">
      <td colname="1">&lt;2&gt;Health care&amp;lt;softreturn&amp;gt;21.27%</td>
      <td colname="2"/>
      <td colname="3"/>
      <td colname="4"/>
      <td colname="5"/>
   </tr>
   <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="4" itemtype="detail" securitymasterkey="1415" securitiescondensed="">
      <td colname="1"/>
      <td colname="2">Gillan Sciences, Inc. Common stocks</td>
      <td colname="3">26,522,142</td>
      <td colname="4">1,132,761</td>
      <td colname="5">4.12</td>
   </tr>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel and @Lingamurthy CS. Both good answers. I would now like to go one stage further though and instead of having the tags hard wired as in <xsl:template match="td[contains(., '[Category Caption]') I would like to be able to use a variable, which I know xslt v. 1.0 will not allow in a template match. I am trying to get a fairly generic template match on the 'td' then try a 'choose' method based on the text containing the value of a variable. Not sure if that would work though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another string function, string-before() to get substring in between the two tokens:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:v4="http://www.v4.com/"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="v4:tr[@type = 'detail' and contains(v4:td/text(),'[Category Caption]')]">
    <xsl:variable name="TargetReplacementToken" select="'[Category Caption]'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="CategoryRecordIdentificationTag" select="'A1>'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="CategoryRemoveToken" select="'[Stop Here]'"/>

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $TargetReplacementToken)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(preceding::v4:tr[@type = 'categoryhead'][last()]/v4:td[contains(text(), $CategoryRecordIdentificationTag)], $CategoryRecordIdentificationTag),$CategoryRemoveToken)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```